# How to run multiple for loops over same range

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to write a piece of code that works something like this

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        for k in range(10):
        # etc etc
```

and would like a cleaner way of writing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you intend to do ? what is inside the etc etc ? Why can't you use simply `for i in range(1000):` ? We need more details.

Comment: So you want to run multiple for loops

Comment: Depends on that ```# etc etc```. Please post what it is.

Comment: why don't you focus first on solving the problem (the `etc etc`) , then if it's too slow/you have nothing better to do maybe think about optimising/improving your code.

Comment: Everything depends on what you want to do. But you're right, having lots of for loops is often not the best-suited solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `product` from `itertools` and pass those 3 ranges.

```py
from itertools import product
for i,j,k in product(range(10), range(10), range(10)):
    # rest of the code
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```py
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 0 3
0 0 4
0 0 5
0 0 6
0 0 7
0 0 8
0 0 9
...
...
9 9 0
9 9 1
9 9 2
9 9 3
9 9 4
9 9 5
9 9 6
9 9 7
9 9 8
9 9 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the range into a variable a re-use it:

```
my_range = range(2)
for i in my_range:
        for j in my_range:
            for k in my_range:
                print(i,j,k)
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually as others mentioned in the comments, it all depends on `# etc etc`. But I'm going to assume that you need to iterate over a structure with three dimensions, say a list or numpy array.
If this is the case i suggest you to take a look at `flatten` and `ravel`.
These two methods get a numpy array and flatten the it's data as the name suggests. Then you can iterate over the flattened array with only one for loop.